# Karate support for validating pipe separated response and avro format

Tags: karate

We have webservice where we send the request body as binary (avro format) through postman and have a pipe separated response. We were able send this request using karate and get a valid  response but made observation that by default karate sets the content type as ‘application/octect-stream’ where as we expect content type to be application/json. Is there a reason why karate uses application/octect-stream for avro format?

Also for pipe separated response does karate support any default validations similar to json/xml validations?

For e.g : if the sample response is like

```
|PDT|! PRODUCT!|Item1|!SKUID!|sku123a|!DETAILS!|Itemname|itemnumber|price|!FINISH!|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate tries to guess the content-type but clearly needs help here, please refer to the documentation for the `header` keyword, and you can set (over-ride) it easily: https://github.com/intuit/karate#header

For the second question, I suggest you write a simple utility to convert that response to JSON and then you will be able to do all kinds of awesome validations in Karate. This example should be self-explanatory: [`dogs.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature)

Comment: I did override the content type with header keyword while sending the request using karate. Regarding the json utility we will take a look at it and will keep you posted

Comment: ok, when Karate sees binary it will not be able to understand whether it is image / avro / exe etc, does that make sense ?

Comment: We do get a valid response so i guess that's ok